# jQuery ajax fired multiple - (once more each passthrough)

Tags: jquery

I have a Problem with my Script using datatables and a jQuery AJAX to insert some data to MySQL:

```
$("#field1").change(function () {
   

    var table = $('#config-table').DataTable({
         responsive:  true,
         processing : true,
         scrollY:     false,
         scrollX:     false,
         destroy:     true,
                      .........


// Table will initialisize correct!
                                           });



$('#config-table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row(this).data();
        console.log(table.row(this).data());
       
        $('#name1').val(data["name1"]);
        $("#responsive-modal").modal("show");

// Button inside the modal
$('#btn1').click(function(){
 var name1 = $("#name1").val();
 var name2 = $("#name2").val();

$.ajax({
                        url: "ajax/InsertNames.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                                name1 : name1,
                                name2 : name2
                                // and more
                              },
                        dataType: "json",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function ()
                        {

                        $('#config-table').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);
                        $("#responsive-modal").modal("hide");


                        },
                        error: function () {
                        alert("ERROR");
                        }

                });

     });

});
```

The Problem is, that after each passthrough the "ajax/InsertNames.php" is called once more. Means, after three table row clicks and pushing the Button "btn1" the "InsertNames.php" is called three times with equal data.

My first solution is like that - changing the click event of "btn1" to jQuery one().

```
$( "#btn1" ).one( "click", function() { ......
```

This works, but I think this is not the correct way to fix it. I would like to understand, why the ajax call is fired multiple.
Can anyone explain that for me?

Thanks a lot!

Regards,
Walter

Comment: `$('#btn1').click`... it is executed every time `tr` is clicked; this does not replace click handler... it ADDs another click handler. Move this outside the tr click handler.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SalmanA ! Very easy! I didn't had in mind, that the click handler (from tr) added up.....